# How to prevent CSS color property applied from parent class to child classes

Tags: css, parent-child

I want to add CSS in `child1` class using parent class name only. I tried this code but CSS is being added in all sub classes of `child1`. I don't want to add CSS in the sub classes of `child1`

```css
.root .child1 {color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="child1">Hi I am child1 of root
    <div class="child12">child2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `child1` is a `div` and you are adding `background-color` to it. It will add color to background of div and will make it red, in result it will make complete div `red` and it will be also be applied to `child` because `child12` is inside that `div`

Comment: what you can do is change the color of the child12 to `white`.

Comment: @XenioGracias yes I did this but CSS is added in all classes

Comment: @BhaktiThakkar What you actually mean by all classes?

Comment: @BearNithi subclasses of child1

Comment: By 'CSS' you mean 'styling', and by 'being added to all classes', you mean 'affecting all children'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent the child classes getting the parent class color, use the following CSS

```
.child1 * {
  color: black;
}
```

`*` selects all the elements which are children of the .child1

If you only want to prevent the direct child of the parent class you can use the following css

```
.child1 > * {
  color: black;
}
```

```css
    .root .child1 {
 background-color: red;
}

.root .child1 div{
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="child1">Hi I am child1 of root
    <div class="child12">child2</div>
    <div class="child13">child3</div>
    <div class="child14">child4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not a great thing to use `*` too much. It's far better to use a relevant selector, like `> div` or add a class to them all and use that (like `child1-children` or something). This cooperates with how CSS works more cleanly.