# What is the smartest way of styling a wrapper, but not propagate the styles to the children element?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, dom

How do I style `.parent` with color `red`without styling `.child`?

One solution would be to overwrite the child element style, but in the real world scenario, the child element will have many complex styles and I do not want to touch them, or overwrite these styles, it would be very risky.

What I want is to add the styles only to the wrapper element. In the real world these two elements will be `<table>` elements

```
<div className="App">
      <div class="parent">
        Parent
        <div>
          <div className="child">child - don't style me</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: check this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54800838/how-to-prevent-css-color-property-applied-from-parent-class-to-child-classes

Comment: Below is how I solved it =D

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all

```
.wrapper {
  color: red;
}

.child {
  all: initial;
}
```

There are other variants, such as `revert-layer`

This may be the best way to not inherit styles from specific cascade style layers without having to depend/know what are these styles to avoid having them overridden.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-goldstine-9hongm?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to reset the property in child, you can use unset.

Eg:

```
.parent {
  color: red;
}

.child {
  color: unset;
}
```

Comment: Did you test this? `unset` for color => `inherit` so this does exactly what the OP doesn't want.